# Months to year(s)

Tags: php, date

I was wondering how can I output in php the number of years for a given amount of months.

For example:

I will give 12 months. The output is: 1 year

I will give 6 months. The output is 6 months

I will give 24 months. The output is 2 years

I will give 18 months. The output is 1 year 6 months

I don`t have any idea how to approach this.

Thanks!

Comment: I would look at the php date function. But you don't even need that for this... divide by 12 for anything over twelve...

Answer (score 2):

What about simple math operations ?

```
$input  = 16;
$months = $input % 12;
$years  = floor($input / 12);
```

Output:

```
$months = 4;
$years  = 1;
```

BTW - in your example you have a mistake - 16 months is not equal to 1 year and 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do.

```
$years= floor($num_months/12).' '.($num_months % 12).' months';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use integer and modular division. The integer division will give the number of years and the modular division will give the number of months:

```
$years = floor($totalMonths / 12);
$months = $totalMonths % 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object and [recalculate carry over points](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#113204) to get correct numbers:

```php
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('16 months');
$from = new DateTime;
$to = clone $from;
$to->add($interval);
$diff = $from->diff($to);
foreach ($diff as $k => $v) $interval->$k = $v;

if ($interval->y && $interval->m) {
    return $interval->format('%y year %m month');
} elseif ($interval->y) {
    return $interval->format('%y year');
} else {
    return $interval->format('%m month');
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/117373)</kbd>

p.s. I hope you can take care of single or plural words?